# Evento CurrentItemChanged de um BindingSource não é chamado ao alterar um subitem

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Tenho uma classe como essa:

```
    public class Foo {

    #region Construtor
    public Foo() { }
    #endregion

    #region Propriedades

    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

e outra:

```
    public class Bar  {

    #region Construtor
    public Bar() { }

    public Bar(int id, string descricao) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Description = descricao;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Propriedades
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Estou realizando o binding dos inputs conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Id = 1;
        foo.Description = "Description foo";
        foo.Bar = new Bar(2, "Bar item 1");

        bindingSource.DataSource = foo;
        // Aqui o binding da descrição da classe Foo
        textBoxFoo.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", bindingSource, "Description", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
        // Aqui o binding da descrição da classe Bar
        textBoxBar.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", bindingSource, "Bar.Description", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);

    }
```

Quando eu altero o input que representa a descrição da classe Foo o evento CurrentItemChanged do BindingSource é chamado corretamente, porém, quando eu altero o input que representa a descrição da classe Bar o evento não é chamado. Alguém poderia me explicar porque isso acontece? Como irei trabalhar com um modelo semelhante a esse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas,  consegui resolver o problema dessa forma:

```
            // Aqui o binding da descrição da classe Bar
        textBoxBar.DataBindings.Add("TEXT", bindingSource, "Bar.Description", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
        textBoxBar.DataBindings[0].BindingManagerBase.CurrentItemChanged += bindingSource_CurrentItemChanged;
```

Tive que adicionar o CurrentItemChanged  no BindingManagerBase novamente...